# Is it good to serve different data from single service or should create separate services for different data, in Angular?

Tags: angular, service

I have different data to be displayed on different components. All this data is just a few lines of code (not more than 12 lines).

So shall I put this in single service and return all the variable or write a separate service for different data?

What is the best approach?

Comment: Point 1 of the SOLID principles is the **single responsability principle** - one class / one service should do **one thing only** - be focused on one thing, and do that well - but don't mix stuff that doesn't belong together. If you have separate "consumers" for your data --> create one focused data service for each topic / consumer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For a better readability/maintainability, one service file per data type is preferable.
It's easier to work with *data1.service.ts* and *data2.service.ts* than with one *global.service.ts*.